# Implementing Auto Forwarding to Next Page in OTree

Tags: python, otree

I have a project in OTree in which there is a game with 3 players. They have 120 seconds to decide whether to press a button or not. If within 120 seconds, any player presses the button, the game ends for all 3 players, and they are shown the result page, or else the timer ends at 120 seconds, and they are shown the result page. 
I am struggling to implement the part where given one player has already clicked the button, the game also ends for the other two players. Specifically, how do I auto-forward to the Results page for the players who have not clicked the button, and hence their forms are not submitted.
Any ideas?